# How do i change the darkness in the border groove?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, css-tables

i was using the groove border but i found out the darkness of some parts dont look dark enough.i have no idea what the command can be when needing to be changed.

i was trying to creat the exact same thing as the first image. (dont mind the text its dutch) the second photo is what i have currently.this is what i have to create(btw dont look at the rest but just the border) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQZ0W.png) this is what i currently have (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lMz4.png)
im scipting with HTML/CSS and i dont use any other code. this is the code that i have for the table. U use a div for the table.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddt4f.png)

Comment: I'd recommend creating a small example of what you are trying to achieve and sharing the code directly in the question rather than via screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this is possible.. Changing the colours (even just the tiniest bit) can make a huge difference though.
You should try:

`border-left: groove #0e8a14;`

`border-top: groove #cf3b2b;`

`border-right: groove #155cad;`

`border-bottom: groove #c2d117;`

Comment: the small changes do make a diffrence in the darkness but only green was the right color, i shall try others too